# How do I match the overall background color of an outer table row in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a nested table. I want all the rows of the inner table to match the background color of the outer table's row they are contained within.  The outer table has a nth-child(odd) and nth-child(even) style set.  The problem is that the inner table is also striped, odd/even.  I just want all the inner table rows background color to be white when the outer table row is white and grey when the outer table row is white.

Comment: setting the inner table's `td`s background-color to transparent should do it

Answer (score 1):

You can use a descendent selector to style a "table in a table". In CSS you would do that like this:

```
table table {}
```

so, if you wanted to style a sub table differently than the parent but still keep zebra striping, you could do something like this:

```css
/*for the outer table*/
table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:#f00;
}
table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#ff0;
}
/*for the inner table*/
table table {margin-left:20px;}
table table tr:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color:transparent; /*transparent to take the color from the parent*/
}
table table tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color:#eee;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td>odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>even</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>
  <table>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  <tr>
  <td>sub-odd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>sub-even</td>
</tr>
  </table>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>even</td>
</tr>
</table>
```